# print function sticks to previous function. Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone so I have this code, I added the (end = " ") so that the print would come out horizontal rather than the default that is vertical, but now this brings me to a problem.

This is my code bellow it you will see my error.

```
def main():
    print ("This line should be ontop of the for loop")
    items = [10,12,18,8,8,9 ]
    for i in items:
        print (i, end= " ")

    print("This line should be ontop of the for loop")
    for x in range(1,50, 5):
        print (x, end = " ")
```

Output:

```
This line should be ontop of the for lopp
10 12 18 8 8 9 This line should be ontop of the for loop
1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
```

Desired Output:

```
This line should be ontop of the for loop
10 12 18 8 8 9 
This line should be ontop of the for loop
1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty print after the loop:

```
for i in items:
    print (i, end= " ")
print()
```

This will print the extra newline you need.

Alternatively, use `str.join()`, `map()` and `str()` to create a new space-separated string from the numbers, printing *that* with the newline:

```
items = [10, 12, 18, 8, 8, 9]
print(' '.join(map(str, items)))
```

and

```
print(' '.join(map(str, range(1,50, 5))))
```